# $A$ be a subset of $[0,1]$ with non-empty interior ; then is it true that $\mathbb Q+A=\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be  a subset of $[0,1]$ with non-empty interior ; then is it true that $\mathbb Q+A=\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: What if $A=(1/3,2/3)$?

Comment: Let $x$ be an interior point of $A$, then there exists an $r>0$ so that $B_r(x) \subset A$. Now $\cup_{p \in \mathbb{Q}} B_r(x+p) = \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. If $A$ has non-empty interior, that means it contains a ball around some point $x \in [0,1]$ of radius $2 r$. Since there's always a rational $q$ less than $r$ away from $y-x$ for any real number $y$, $y$ will be in the ball centered at $q+x$ of radius $2r$ in $q + A$, which is contained in $\mathbb{Q}+A$.

Answer (score -1):

ℝ=ℚ +ℚ̅(irrational numbers),what ever we choose A other than irrational numbers,it is not possible to cover all ℝ,
so ℚ+A will be the proper subset of ℝ.

Comment: I think you are confusing the sum $+$ (_i.e._, $A+B = \{ a+b : a \in A, b \in B \}$) with the union $\cup$.